# React Hooks: Too many re-renders on switch mode

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to improve my switch theme code but I have the following error:

> Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to
>   prevent an infinite loop.

My code:

```
export default function App() {
  const theme = useTheme();

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <div className="App">
        <button
          css={css`
            background: red;
            width: 100px;
            height: 50px;
            border-radius: 10px;
          `}
          onClick={theme.setTheme(
            theme.type === 'dark' ? { type: 'light' } : { type: 'dark' },
          )}
        >
          a
        </button>
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

My hook:

```
   export default function useTheme(defaultTheme = lightTheme) {
  const [theme, _setTheme] = useState(getInitialTheme);

  function getInitialTheme() {
    const savedTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
    return savedTheme === 'dark' ? darkTheme : defaultTheme;
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('theme', JSON.stringify(theme.type));
  }, [theme]);

  return {
    ...theme,
    setTheme: ({ setTheme, ...theme }) => {
      if (theme.type === 'dark') {
        return _setTheme(darkTheme);
      } else {
        return _setTheme(lightTheme);
      }
    },
  };
}
```

I would also like to know how I could get what was sent on my `setTheme`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
onClick={theme.setTheme(
        theme.type === 'dark' ? { type: 'light' } : { type: 'dark' },
      )}
```

To

```
onClick={() => theme.setTheme(theme.type === 'dark' ? { type: 'light' } : { type: 'dark' })}
```

In your code, you are immediately executing setTheme during render and it is causing  another render and recursively endless rendering, which is stopped by react. onClick prop expects a function as the value, that function will be executed during click.

Comment: Hello thank you so much,
 do you think the code is good?
Could you tell me if I can show something?